# Custom Symfony Bundle with Entities

Tags: php, symfony

I want to create a symfony bundle for a Role and Right system. I want to provide the user of this bundle with the necessary entities. I want to make it so that the user can still edit the entities. In other words, I want to move the entities from my bundle to the symfony project of the end user (src/Entity/). This way the end user can still customize the entities should he or she wish to do so.

I have been Googling a fair bit and the only things I found were symfony recipes and a custom symfony-maker class. The problem with recipes are that you have to get approved by symfony. The custom maker bundle on the otherhand confuses me to no end.

Do any of you have some tips? This is my first time that I am making a Symfony bundle and there are not that many great resources.

Comment: You can extend the entities inside your project !

Comment: Thanks @AlexandrePainchaud I'll try it but I have one question though. Do you still have to define all the properties and methods in the subclass or do you just make all the properties and methods protected in the original entity (the ones inside my bundle)?

Comment: i wrote an answer, if it helps you do not forget to mark it as resolved ;)

Comment: There is a reason you won't find many examples of this sort of thing.  Doctrine does not lend itself well for this sort of thing.  I see you accepted the mapped superclass answer below which is great.  But there are many limitations on Doctrine inheritance which I expect you will quickly run into.  Read and understand the link in the answer carefully.  Might try something a bit easier for your first bundle.

Comment: I understand what you mean. I was thinking of just creating the entities and include them in the bundle. I then want to create a symfony command that copies the files from my bundle to the Entities folder of the end user. What do you think about that @Cerad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i told you, you can extend Doctrine Entities (https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/inheritance-mapping.html)

```
/** @ORM\MappedSuperclass */
class A {
   /** @ORM\Column(type="integer") */
   protected $id;

   /** @ORM\Column(type="string") */
   protected $title;
}
/** @ORM\Entity */
class B extends A {
   /** @ORM\Column(type="string") */
   protected $author;
}
```

So you do not have to define all properties.